# PhantomJS error: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('system').create()')

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, phantomjs

UPDATE:: PROBLEM SOLVED, I WAS ABLE TO ISOLATE IT SPECIFICALLY TO MY JAVASCRIPT FILE.

cap_screen.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); //Create a new instance of a web page
var system = require('system').create(); //Our script needs to require Phantom's Web Page module


page.onError = function(msg, trace) { //Our script needs to require Phantom's Web Page module

    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msg.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
        });
    }

    console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

//Now write core of screen cap script
//Remember: system.args[1] = "http://wwww.clowder.com" system.args[2] = "clowder-pic.png"
page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.render(system.args[2]); //this line captures the screen
    phantom.exit();
});
```

My problem is when submitting a URL, the following error pops up:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('system').create()')
  phantomjs://code/cap_screen.js:10 in global code
```

This is my code:

entries_controller

```
 def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
    @entry.image = cap_screen
    if @entry.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render('index')
    end
  end
  private

  PATH_TO_PHANTOM_SCRIPT = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts', 'cap_screen.js')
  def cap_screen
    Dir.chdir(Rails.root.join('public', 'images'))
    system "phantomjs #{PATH_TO_PHANTOM_SCRIPT} #{params['entry_url']} #    {params['entry_url']}.png"
  end

  def entry_params
     params.require(:entry).permit(:title, :url)
  end
```

In my cap_screen.js file, my IDE gives me the warning "Unresolved variable or type phantom".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who have had problems with `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor`, for my problem, I accidentally had the line:

`var system = require('system').create();`

When it should have been

`var system = require('system')`

Answer (score 0):

If it is in Spec file, Make sure you have the function create() in the provider class(In the below example MockService needs the function).

```
{
provide: .....Service,
useClass: MockService
}

export class MockService {
create() {
// your code for test
}
constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but for a different string function.

> **TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'inputValue.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z,]/g,'')')**

My fix was to add "**.toString()**" between the variable and the ".replace" method call. I've included my code below for further reference.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mo.pages.global-search.directives')
        .directive('extentionListValidate', restrictTextfieldToAlphaNumericList);

function restrictTextfieldToAlphaNumericList() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue ? inputValue.toString().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z,]/g, '') : null;

                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
}
})();
```